# Java Dom API getAttribute

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

im trying to parse xml file, but it wont print attribut value. I dont know how to get attribute typ from phone

```
 try {  String subor = "Noviny.xml";
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(subor);
System.out.println("----------------\n");
NodeList nodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("Author");
NodeList nodelist1 = document.getElementsByTagName("Article");
for(int i = 0; i < nodelist.getLength(); i++) {
  Node uzol = nodelist.item(i);
  if (uzol.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
  {
      Element element = (Element) uzol;
      System.out.println("Id:" + element.getElementsByTagName("Id").item(0).getTextContent() + "\n"); 
      System.out.println("Name:" + element.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent() + "\n");
      System.out.println("Email:" + element.getElementsByTagName("Email").item(0).getTextContent() + "\n");
      System.out.println("typ: " + element.getAttribute("typ") + "\n");
      System.out.println("phone:" + element.getElementsByTagName("phone").item(0).getTextContent() + "\n");
      System.out.println("typ: " + element.getAttribute("typ") + "\n");
      System.out.println("sal: " + element.getElementsByTagName("sal").item(0).getTextContent() + "\n"); 
    }


    catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and xml

```
<Noviny>
  <Author>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>first</Name>
    <Email>first@gmail.com</Email>
    <phone typ="mobil">09443916565</phone>  
    <sal>500</sal>
  </Author>
  <Author>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>second</Name>
    <Email>second@gmail.com</Email>
    <phone typ="pevna">094415665465</phone>  
    <sal>1000</sal>
  </Author>
```

and one more thing:ňIs it possible to just print (System.out.println) tree representation of xml file?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` is a `Author` element node and has no attributes. The `typ` attribute is on the `phone` tag

```
Element phone = (Element)element.getElementsByTagName("phone").item(0);
System.out.println("typ: " + phone.getAttribute("typ") + "\n");
```

For the second part, try

```
Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
System.out.println(root.toString());
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got error: cannot find symbol - method getAttribure